# Recursive ArrayPush in Javascript to get all combination

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

```
var Combination = [];

function Reduce(List, Target) {
        if(List.length > 1) {
            return Reduce(List.filter(word => word !== List[0]), List[1]);
        } else {
            return List[0];
        }
    }
```

If user input `X = ["AB, "DE", "SZ", "YY"]`, above function have to return all possible combination like `["AB", "DE"], ["AB", "YY", "SZ"]` .

I'm trying to solve it in recursive way, but stuck at pushing result to `Combination`.
Where do I have to change to get all possible combinations?

If my approach is wrong, thanks for the correction in advance

Comment: `X = ["AB, "DE", "SZ", "YY"]` you forgot to close quotes on `AB` element

Comment: what is the purpose of `Target` in your function if you are not gonna use it?

Comment: With a [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) the order of selection does not matter, but looking at your example, you seem to give importance to order: `["AB", "YY", "SZ"]` does not list the elements in their original order. Does that mean you regard `["AB", "SZ", "YY"]` as a *different* "combination"?

Comment: What is your reasoning to pass `List[1]` as second argument in the recursive call? What should happen if your input list has duplicates?

Comment: @trincot As you have mentioned, differenet element orders will be considered as individual combination.

If recursive occurs within `Reduce()` while length of List is more than 0 and due to list.filter(), I expected `List[0]` will be filtered and set the target as List[1] so that `Reduce()` can use target to filter rest of elements.

As a result, when User input List as `["AB", "CD", EA"]`, `Reduce()` has to return `[["AB", "CD", "EA], ["AB", "CD"], ["AB"], ["CD", "EA"]` and etc.

If my question wasn't clear enough, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: OK. Can input have duplicate elements? How does that impact expected output?

Comment: @trincot There will be no repetition within elements. Thus there will be no impacts to outcomes!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of your inputs, that is, the set of all subsets of your set.  For instance, the power set of `[1, 2, 3]` is:

```js
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

This includes the first, empty array, and every other combination of the elements.  There will be `2 ^ n` elements in the set, where `n` is the length of your original set.  Note that although this is an array, it is theoretically an unordered collection.

Here is one version of `powerSet`:

```js
const powerSet = ([x, ...xs]) =>
  x == undefined 
    ? [[]]
    : powerSet (xs) .flatMap (p => [p, [x, ...p]])


console .log (powerSet ([1, 2, 3]) .map (ss => ss.join ('/')))
console .log (powerSet (["AB", "DE", "SZ", "YY"]) .map (ss => ss.join('/')))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

(We add the `.join('/')` just to make it easier to see on the console.  The result is an array of arrays.)

We recur on the tail of the array, keeping those values as well as the sets found by including the head of the array alongside the values of that subset.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe are all permutations of all subsets of an n-set.

One way to produce those is to use a generator function:

```js
function* permutationsOfSubSets([first, ...rest]) {
    if (first === undefined) return yield [];
    for (const result of permutationsOfSubSets(rest)) {
        yield result; // The result without first value...
        // ...and extended with the first value injected at every possible index
        for (let injectAt = 0; injectAt <= result.length; injectAt++) {
            yield [...result.slice(0, injectAt), first, ...result.slice(injectAt)];
        }
    }
}

// Example run
const arr = ["AB", "DE", "SZ"];
// Iterate the results and print them
for (const result of permutationsOfSubSets(arr)) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
// If you need them as array:
const results = [...permutationsOfSubSets(arr)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function combinations(list) {
  const results = [];
  for (const item of list) {
    const length = results.length;
    // add the combination that contains only the item
    results.push([item]);
    // for each of the previous combinations ...
    for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      // ... add a copy/version with item
      results.push([...results[i], item]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(combinations([1, 2, 3, 4]).join("\n"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

You could write this in a recursive manner, but it would be more complicated and would create way more throwaway arrays in the process.

---

Another approach that is a bit more academic. Think numbers in binary, and each position tells if this item is included in this particular combination.
That means for `n` items in the list you need to go up to combination `(2 ** n)-1` which is just `n` ones.

So you count up and check the bits which items of the `list` it contains.

```js
function combinations(list) {
  const length = 2 ** list.length;
  const results = [];
  // combination == 0 would be empty.
  for (let combination = 1; combination < length; ++combination) {
    results.push(list.filter((_, col) => combination & (1 << col)));
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(combinations([1, 2, 3, 4]).join("\n"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```